# How do I create custom stanzas in MongooseIM?

Tags: erlang, xmpp, elixir, mongoose-im

I need a way to create customized stanzas and have mongooseIM recognize them and store the data accordingly inside of a given database such as mysql for later retrieval.

The reason I want to do this is because an app that I am building has a chat that requires complex querying based on sub objects'parameters. Also anything a user does inside of the app but outside of the chat like change the title of the group chat or like a post, it is logged inside of the chat as a log message with the given postId and userId.

So ideally I want it to do something like this:

```html
<postId>1</postId> //So that I can query by post id
<description>Hello</description> //Data for clients to update real time
<userId>1</userId> //also want to be able to query the db by this.
```

all these variables should be saved into the database that is provided for MAM inside of the MongooseIM

Answer (score 0):

You need to rite your custom mod in erlang. Here is how you can start on this :

https://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide/Getting-started/

Build and install from source code

To build and install MongooseIM from source code, do the following:

Clone the Git repository:  git clone https://github.com/esl/MongooseIM.git
Go to your MongooseIM directory.
Run the following command: make rel.

In the code You will see apps/ejabberd/src

Write you mode these and compile to get bin file and move the bin files to the release.